# If X is an uncountable set, will countably many random draws be dense in X?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm interested in how large samples would approximate a distribution.

Suppose $X$ is a set of finite dimension of uncountable cardinality. If I take countably many i.i.d. random draws from the set according to a distribution with full support, will those sampled draws be almost surely dense in $X$?

I would try a proof on $X=[0,1]$ with uniform draws by contradiction. Suppose it isn't true. Then, there is some neighborhood of length $d$ where no sampled points lie. From $n$ draws, this event has probability $(1-d)^{n}$. Send $n\rightarrow\infty$, for $d>0$ this event has zero probability.

For $[0,1]^{n}$, simply imagine $d$ as a measure and the proof stays the same, even with a new distribution?

And we also maintain probability zero of drawing two identical points?

Is it even sensible to talk about uncountably many random draws?

Thanks

Comment: What if you consider $[0,1]\cup\{2\}$ with uniform distribution?

Comment: Good point. I'm happy to impose $X$ connected. That seems necessary.

Comment: @Pburg not if $X = [0,1]\setminus \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: If we have a probability Borel measure on a space where all open sets have strictly positive measure, I think the same argument will work. This also takes care of $[0,1]\cup\{2\}$ as the singleton is an open set of measure $0$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom what's wrong with the irrationals? I think they will work..

Comment: @HennoBrandsma a uniform set of random draws will be dense in the irrationals in $[0,1]$, even though this set is completely disconnected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set is dense in $X$ if and only if it intersects every element of a basis of topology for $X$. The spaces we are most familiar with, like $[0,1]$, $\mathbb R$, $\mathbb R^d$ and their subsets, have a *countable* basis of topology. Let $\{U_n\}$ be such a basis.

If $P(U_n)=0$ for some $n$, then your countable sample will almost surely miss $U_n$, hence will not be dense.

If $P(U_n)>0$, then the probability of the sample being disjoint from $U_n$ is zero, because $\lim_{k\to\infty } (1-P(U_n))^k = 0$. The union of countably many events of probability zero still has probability zero. Therefore, the countable sample will be dense almost surely.

---

> And we also maintain probability zero of drawing two identical points?

Yes. If $P(\{x\})=0$ for every $x\in X$, then the probability of drawing a point that was  drawn at a previous step is zero.

---

> Is it even sensible to talk about uncountably many random draws?

Sensible, but not as easy as in the countable case. See  [continuous-time white noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise#Continuous-time_white_noise).